# Can’t login Google Drive

Tags: login, google-drive

My Google drive account does not sync, or when I re-install Google Drive application, I can’t login in my account because it appears:

> Error on page

Sometimes when I try to access this website (`https//accounts.google.com`) Internet Explorer can’t access and show the same error than Google drive login.

I have tried to change the security things to try to login, but I can’t login.

What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like Google Drive is being blocked by your network.  More information is required to help.

Comment: i have tried turning off anti-virus , change security things on IE but i have the same problem

Comment: This a home network or corporate network? It sounds like Google Drive is being specifically block by the network, if its a corporate  network, talk to the network Administrator about it.

Comment: Is that you are facing the same issue in google chrome also. Some time due to browser issue you might face the issue

Comment: Please add more information to your post. Which security settings did you modify? When you turn of user friendly error messages in Internet Explorer, do you get a more specific error message? There is not much information to go with.

Answer (score -1):

Just *Run as administrator* and you can login as usual:

[image]